# Pivot Point OHLC Calculation

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am having issues identifying the specifics on the High/Low calculation that need changing to plot the pivots in the same location as another script.

Script 1 is what I wish to have the same calculation for the intraday pivots as script 2, but currently they plot differently. I have attached an image to show with script 1 in the lighter colors vs script 2 in darker.

The initial Pivot calculation is based on a different value therefore causing all pivots to be out of sync. I believe it is due to the OHLC variation (current and previous), but everything I have tried fails to execute the pivots in the same way as script 2.

Script 1:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Fib Pivots 1", "FP1", overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500)

AUTO = "Auto"
Min15 = "15 Min"
Hour1 = "1 Hour"
Hour4 = "4 Hour"
DAILY = "Daily"
WEEKLY = "Weekly"
MONTHLY = "Monthly"
QUARTERLY = "Quarterly"
YEARLY = "Yearly"


FIBONACCI = "Fibonacci"




pivot_time_frame = input.string(title="Pivots Timeframe", defval=AUTO, options=[AUTO, Min15, Hour1, Hour4, DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY, QUARTERLY, YEARLY])
look_back = input.int(title="Number of Pivots Back", defval=15, minval=1, maxval=5000)
is_daily_based = input.bool(title="Use Daily-based Values", defval=true, tooltip="When this option is unchecked, Pivot Points will use intraday data while calculating on intraday charts. If Extended Hours are displayed on the chart, they will be taken into account during the pivot level calculation. If intraday OHLC values are different from daily-based values (normal for stocks), the pivot levels will also differ.")
show_labels = input.bool(title="Show Labels", defval=true, group="labels")
show_prices = input.bool(title="Show Prices", defval=false, group="labels")
position_labels = input.string("Left", "Labels Position", options=["Left", "Right"], group="labels")
line_width = input.int(title="Line Width", defval=1, minval=1, maxval=100, group="levels")

colorR = #4cafa2

colorP = #ffea00

colorS = #ff00dd

var arr_time = array.new_int()
var p = array.new_float()
p_color = input.color(colorP, "P", inline="P", group="levels")
p_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="P", group="levels")
var r1 = array.new_float()
var s1 = array.new_float()
s1_color = input.color(colorS, "S1", inline="S1/R1" , group="levels")
s1_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="S1/R1", group="levels")
r1_color = input.color(colorR, "R1", inline="S1/R1", group="levels")
r1_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="S1/R1", group="levels")
var r2 = array.new_float()
var s2 = array.new_float()
s2_color = input.color(colorS, "S2", inline="S2/R2", group="levels")
s2_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="S2/R2", group="levels")
r2_color = input.color(colorR, "R2", inline="S2/R2", group="levels")
r2_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="S2/R2", group="levels")
var r3 = array.new_float()
var s3 = array.new_float()
s3_color = input.color(colorS, "S3", inline="S3/R3", group="levels")
s3_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="S3/R3", group="levels")
r3_color = input.color(colorR, "R3", inline="S3/R3", group="levels")
r3_show = input.bool(true, "", inline="S3/R3", group="levels")


pivotX_open = float(0.)
pivotX_open := nz(pivotX_open[1], open)
pivotX_high = float(0.)
pivotX_high := nz(pivotX_high[1], high)
pivotX_low = float(0.)
pivotX_low := nz(pivotX_low[1], low)
pivotX_prev_open = float(0.)
pivotX_prev_open := nz(pivotX_prev_open[1])
pivotX_prev_high = float(0.)
pivotX_prev_high := nz(pivotX_prev_high[1])
pivotX_prev_low = float(0.)
pivotX_prev_low := nz(pivotX_prev_low[1])
pivotX_prev_close = float(0.)
pivotX_prev_close := nz(pivotX_prev_close[1])

get_pivot_resolution() =>
    resolution = "M"
    if pivot_time_frame == AUTO
        if timeframe.isintraday
            resolution := timeframe.multiplier <= 15 ? "D" : "W"
        else if timeframe.isweekly or timeframe.ismonthly
            resolution := "12M"
    else if pivot_time_frame == Min15
        resolution := "15"
    else if pivot_time_frame == Hour1
        resolution := "60"
    else if pivot_time_frame == Hour4
        resolution := "240"
    else if pivot_time_frame == DAILY
        resolution := "D"
    else if pivot_time_frame == WEEKLY
        resolution := "W"
    else if pivot_time_frame == MONTHLY
        resolution := "M"
    else if pivot_time_frame == QUARTERLY
        resolution := "3M"
    else if pivot_time_frame == YEARLY
        resolution := "12M"
    resolution

var lines = array.new_line()
var labels = array.new_label()

draw_line(i, pivot, col) =>
    if array.size(arr_time) > 1
        array.push(lines, line.new(array.get(arr_time, i), array.get(pivot, i), array.get(arr_time, i + 1), array.get(pivot, i), color=col, xloc=xloc.bar_time, width=line_width))

draw_label(i, y, txt, txt_color) =>
    if (show_labels or show_prices) and not na(y)
        display_text = (show_labels ? txt : "") + (show_prices ? str.format(" ({0})", math.round_to_mintick(y)) : "")
        label_style = position_labels == "Left" ? label.style_label_right : label.style_label_left
        x = position_labels == "Left" ? array.get(arr_time, i) : array.get(arr_time, i + 1)
        array.push(labels, label.new(x = x, y=y, text=display_text, textcolor=txt_color, style=label_style, color=#00000000, xloc=xloc.bar_time))


fibonacci() =>
    pivotX_Median = math.avg(pivotX_prev_high, pivotX_prev_low, pivotX_prev_close)
    pivot_range = pivotX_prev_high - pivotX_prev_low
    array.push(p, pivotX_Median)
    array.push(r3, pivotX_Median + pivot_range)
    array.push(r2, pivotX_Median + pivot_range * 0.618)
    array.push(r1, pivotX_Median + pivot_range * 0.382)
    array.push(s1, pivotX_Median - pivot_range * 0.382)
    array.push(s2, pivotX_Median - pivot_range * 0.618)
    array.push(s3, pivotX_Median - pivot_range)

calc_pivot() => fibonacci()


resolution = get_pivot_resolution()

SIMPLE_DIVISOR = -1
custom_years_divisor = switch pivot_time_frame
    => SIMPLE_DIVISOR

calc_high(prev, curr) =>
    if na(prev) or na(curr)
        nz(prev, nz(curr, na))
    else
        math.max(prev, curr)
    
calc_low(prev, curr) =>
    if not na(prev) and not na(curr)
        math.min(prev, curr)
    else
        nz(prev, nz(curr, na))

calc_OHLC_for_pivot(custom_years_divisor) =>
    if custom_years_divisor == SIMPLE_DIVISOR 
        [open, high, low, close, open[1], high[1], low[1], close[1], time[1], time_close]
    else
        var prev_sec_open = float(na)
        var prev_sec_high = float(na)
        var prev_sec_low = float(na)
        var prev_sec_close = float(na)
        var prev_sec_time = int(na)
        var curr_sec_open = float(na)
        var curr_sec_high = float(na)
        var curr_sec_low = float(na)
        var curr_sec_close = float(na)
        if year(time_close) % custom_years_divisor == 0
            curr_sec_open := open
            curr_sec_high := high
            curr_sec_low := low
            curr_sec_close := close
            prev_sec_high := high[1]
            prev_sec_low := low[1]
            prev_sec_close := close[1]
            prev_sec_time := time[1]
            for i = 2 to custom_years_divisor
                prev_sec_open :=  nz(open[i], prev_sec_open)
                prev_sec_high := calc_high(prev_sec_high, high[i])
                prev_sec_low := calc_low(prev_sec_low, low[i])
                prev_sec_time := nz(time[i], prev_sec_time)
        [curr_sec_open, curr_sec_high, curr_sec_low, curr_sec_close, prev_sec_open, prev_sec_high, prev_sec_low, prev_sec_close, prev_sec_time, time_close]

[sec_open, sec_high, sec_low, sec_close, prev_sec_open, prev_sec_high, prev_sec_low, prev_sec_close, prev_sec_time, sec_time] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, calc_OHLC_for_pivot(custom_years_divisor), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
sec_open_gaps_on = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, open, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

is_change_years = custom_years_divisor > 0 and ta.change(time(resolution)) and year(time_close) % custom_years_divisor == 0

var is_change = false
var change_time = int(na)
is_time_change = (ta.change(time(resolution)) and custom_years_divisor == SIMPLE_DIVISOR) or is_change_years
if is_time_change
    change_time := time

var start_time = time
var was_last_premarket = false
var start_calculate_in_premarket = false

is_last_premarket = barstate.islast and session.ispremarket and time_close > sec_time and not was_last_premarket

if is_last_premarket
    was_last_premarket := true
    start_calculate_in_premarket := true
if session.ismarket
    was_last_premarket := false
    
without_time_change = barstate.islast and array.size(arr_time) == 0
is_can_calc_pivot = (is_time_change and session.ismarket) or (ta.change(sec_open) and not start_calculate_in_premarket) or is_last_premarket or without_time_change
enough_bars_for_calculate = prev_sec_time >= start_time or is_daily_based

if is_can_calc_pivot and enough_bars_for_calculate 
    if array.size(arr_time) == 0 and is_daily_based
        pivotX_prev_open := prev_sec_open[1]
        pivotX_prev_high := prev_sec_high[1]
        pivotX_prev_low := prev_sec_low[1]
        pivotX_prev_close := prev_sec_close[1]
        pivotX_open := sec_open[1]
        pivotX_high := sec_high[1]
        pivotX_low := sec_low[1]
        array.push(arr_time, start_time)
        calc_pivot()
    
    if is_daily_based
        if is_last_premarket
            pivotX_prev_open := sec_open
            pivotX_prev_high := sec_high
            pivotX_prev_low := sec_low
            pivotX_prev_close := sec_close
            pivotX_open := open
            pivotX_high := high
            pivotX_low := low
        else
            pivotX_prev_open := prev_sec_open
            pivotX_prev_high := prev_sec_high
            pivotX_prev_low := prev_sec_low
            pivotX_prev_close := prev_sec_close
            pivotX_open := sec_open
            pivotX_high := sec_high
            pivotX_low := sec_low
    else
        pivotX_prev_high := pivotX_high
        pivotX_prev_low := pivotX_low
        pivotX_prev_open := pivotX_open
        pivotX_prev_close := close[1]
        pivotX_open := open
        pivotX_high := high
        pivotX_low := low

    if barstate.islast and not is_change and array.size(arr_time) > 0 and not without_time_change
        array.set(arr_time, array.size(arr_time) - 1, change_time)
    else if without_time_change
        array.push(arr_time, start_time)
    else
        array.push(arr_time, nz(change_time, time))

    calc_pivot()

    if array.size(arr_time) > look_back
        if array.size(arr_time) > 0
            array.shift(arr_time)
        if array.size(p) > 0 and p_show
            array.shift(p)
        if array.size(r1) > 0 and r1_show
            array.shift(r1)
        if array.size(s1) > 0 and s1_show
            array.shift(s1)
        if array.size(r2) > 0 and r2_show
            array.shift(r2)
        if array.size(s2) > 0 and s2_show
            array.shift(s2)
        if array.size(r3) > 0 and r3_show
            array.shift(r3)
        if array.size(s3) > 0 and s3_show
            array.shift(s3)
    is_change := true
else if not is_daily_based
    pivotX_high := math.max(pivotX_high, high)
    pivotX_low := math.min(pivotX_low, low)

if barstate.islast and not is_daily_based and array.size(arr_time) == 0 
    runtime.error("Not enough intraday data to calculate Pivot Points. Lower the Pivots Timeframe or turn on the 'Use Daily-based Values' option in the indicator settings.")

if barstate.islast and array.size(arr_time) > 0 and is_change
    is_change := false
    if custom_years_divisor > 0
        last_pivot_time = array.get(arr_time, array.size(arr_time) - 1)
        pivot_timeframe = str.tostring(12 * custom_years_divisor) + "M"
        estimate_pivot_time = last_pivot_time + timeframe.in_seconds(pivot_timeframe) * 1000
        array.push(arr_time, estimate_pivot_time)
    else
        array.push(arr_time, time_close(resolution))

    for i = 0 to array.size(lines) - 1
        if array.size(lines) > 0
            line.delete(array.shift(lines))
        if array.size(labels) > 0
            label.delete(array.shift(labels))

    for i = 0 to array.size(arr_time) - 2
        if array.size(p) > 0 and p_show
            draw_line(i, p, p_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(p, i), "P", p_color)
        if array.size(r1) > 0 and r1_show
            draw_line(i, r1, r1_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r1, i), "R1", r1_color)
        if array.size(s1) > 0 and s1_show
            draw_line(i, s1, s1_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s1, i), "S1", s1_color)
        if array.size(r2) > 0 and r2_show
            draw_line(i, r2, r2_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r2, i), "R2", r2_color)
        if array.size(s2) > 0 and s2_show
            draw_line(i, s2, s2_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s2, i), "S2", s2_color)
        if array.size(r3) > 0 and r3_show
            draw_line(i, r3, r3_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(r3, i), "R3", r3_color)
        if array.size(s3) > 0 and s3_show
            draw_line(i, s3, s3_color)
            draw_label(i, array.get(s3, i), "S3", s3_color)
```

The following script has the correct location for the pivots I wish to have in script 1.

Script 2:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Fib Pivots 2', shorttitle='FP2', overlay=true)

// Function outputs 1 when it's the first bar of the D/W/M/Y
is_newbar(res) =>
    ch = 0
    if res == 'Y'
        t = year(time('D'))
        ch := ta.change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
        ch
    else
        t = time(res)
        ch := ta.change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
        ch
    ch

////////////
// INPUTS //
////////////

pp_period = input.string(title='Period', defval='Day', options=['Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Year'])

pp_res = pp_period == 'Day' ? 'D' : pp_period == 'Week' ? 'W' : pp_period == 'Month' ? 'M' : 'Y'

/////////////////////
// Get HLC from HT //

// Calc High
high_cur = 0.0
high_cur := is_newbar(pp_res) ? high : math.max(high_cur[1], high)

phigh = 0.0
phigh := is_newbar(pp_res) ? high_cur[1] : phigh[1]

// Calc Low
low_cur = 0.0
low_cur := is_newbar(pp_res) ? low : math.min(low_cur[1], low)

plow = 0.0
plow := is_newbar(pp_res) ? low_cur[1] : plow[1]

// Calc Close
pclose = 0.0
pclose := is_newbar(pp_res) ? close[1] : pclose[1]

////////////////////////////////
// CALCULATE fibonacci pivots //

vPP = math.avg(phigh, plow, pclose)

vR3 = vPP + (phigh - plow) * 1.000
vR2 = vPP + (phigh - plow) * 0.618
vR1 = vPP + (phigh - plow) * 0.382

vS1 = vPP - (phigh - plow) * 0.382
vS2 = vPP - (phigh - plow) * 0.618
vS3 = vPP - (phigh - plow) * 1.000

//////////////
// PLOTTING //

bars_sinse = 0
bars_sinse := is_newbar(pp_res) ? 0 : bars_sinse[1] + 1

////////////////////////
// PLOT PIVOTS LEVELS //

colorR = input.color(#003bc5)


colorP = input.color(#957200)


colorS = input.color(#5100ff)

vpp_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vPP, bar_index, vPP, color=colorP, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)

vr1_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vR1, bar_index, vR1, color=colorR, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)
vr2_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vR2, bar_index, vR2, color=colorR, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)
vr3_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vR3, bar_index, vR3, color=colorR, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)

vs1_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vS1, bar_index, vS1, color=colorS, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)
vs2_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vS2, bar_index, vS2, color=colorS, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)
vs3_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vS3, bar_index, vS3, color=colorS, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.right)

// delete previous lines in the same period
if not is_newbar(pp_res)
    line.delete(vpp_p[1])
    line.delete(vr1_p[1])
    line.delete(vr2_p[1])
    line.delete(vr3_p[1])
    line.delete(vs1_p[1])
    line.delete(vs2_p[1])
    line.delete(vs3_p[1])

// delete entend for the old lines
if is_newbar(pp_res)
    line.set_extend(vpp_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vr1_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vr2_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vr3_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vs1_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vs2_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vs3_p[1], extend.none)


// Add labels
if is_newbar(pp_res)
    label_vpp = label.new(bar_index, vPP, text='P', style=label.style_none)
    label_vr1 = label.new(bar_index, vR1, text='R1', style=label.style_none)
    label_vr2 = label.new(bar_index, vR2, text='R2', style=label.style_none)
    label_vr3 = label.new(bar_index, vR3, text='R3', style=label.style_none)
    label_vs1 = label.new(bar_index, vS1, text='S1', style=label.style_none)
    label_vs2 = label.new(bar_index, vS2, text='S2', style=label.style_none)
    label_vs3 = label.new(bar_index, vS3, text='S3', style=label.style_none)
    label_vs3
```

[Script 1 (lighter - aqua, yellow & magenta) vs Script 2 (darker - blue, orange & purple)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYxik.png)